# Digit or Number limit with exact match on Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python 2.7.3 I have the following function:

```
def is2To4Numbers(q):
    if re.match('[0-9]{2,4}',q):return True
    else: return False
```

I'm trying to limit the number of digits from 2 to 4. But I get these results.

```
>>> is2To4Numbers('1235')
True

>>> is2To4Numbers('1')
False

>>> is2To4Numbers('12345')
True

>>> is2To4Numbers('1234567890')
True
```

I can't seem to get the right limit. How should i solve this? Are there other ways other than using {m,n}? Or am I even using {m,n} correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your regex just looks for 2 to 4 digits which exist inside your larger number.  Add this:

```
'^[0-9]{2,4}$'
```

It might be a lot easier to just to use the built in numeric test and add greater than and a less than check like this:

```
def is2To4Numbers(q):
    try:
        return 10 <= int(q) <= 9999
    except:
        return False
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to search for exactly 2-to-4 digits in a larger string, and hence can not use `^` and `$` as part of the pattern, then you could use [negative look-behind](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) (`?<!`) and negative look-ahead (`?!`):

```
import re

def is2To4Numbers(q):
    return bool(re.search(r'''(?x)    # verbose mode
                              (?<!\d) # not preceded by a digit 
                              \d{2,4} # 2-to-4 digits
                              (?!\d)  # not followed by a digit
                              ''',q))

tests = ['1', '12', '123', '1234', '12345', 'foo12', '123bar']
for test in tests:
    print('{t:6} => {r}'.format(t = test, r = is2To4Numbers(test)))
```

yields

```
1      => False
12     => True
123    => True
1234   => True
12345  => False
foo12  => True
123bar => True
```

Comment: No. I'm not searching for the number. But, I'm looking for the exact match that is valid. But, this is good to know. Thanks for the `^` advice